# Would there be a performance difference if CSS is written minimizing the amount a property is called instead of a selector?

Tags: css, performance, load, stylesheet, minify

To clarify:

Right now, most likely due to readability, CSS is written somewhat like so:

```
element {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#selector {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.selector-two {
    color: red;
}
```

In this example, properties are assigned to selectors to give them a certain style. Also, certain properties are assigned multiple times to different selectors. Would there be a difference in performance or size of the stylesheet if it was written like so:

```
element, #selector { text-decoration: underline; }
#selector, .selector-two { color: red; }
#selector { font-size: 50px; }
```

Of course this wouldn't make it easy to see in the CSS which styles are applied to certain elements, but would there be any benefits if you can minify your CSS code to look this?

Comment: Almost any form of CSS refactoring for performance is premature optimization. Browser engines are blazingly fast with CSS selectors. Write whatever is most readable and maintainable for you.

Comment: I agree that the performance gains would be minimal, but that's pretty much what [Sass's extend](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#how_it_works) does.

Comment: Better spend your time optimizing the *structure* of your CSS.  Some structures are much more time-consuming to apply (not to parse) than others.  There is much discussion to be found on the net regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS speed optimisation is a complete waste of time.

Browsers can parse that stuff ridiculously quickly.

You'd be better off focusing on reducing the file size of your collateral, i.e. your images, css files, html, javascript, etc.